How do Spider-Man's pockets work?
In the Secret Wars #6 (2015) comic book, there was a humorous scene that revealed Spider-Man (Miles Morales) had been carrying a burger in his pocket.

This detail seems a bit odd to me, considering that the Spider-Man suits of both Peter and Miles are skin-tight, seemingly leaving very little to no room for storing items like burgers without creating a noticeable (and inconvenient) bulge. (…And that's likely why Batman rocks that trusty utility belt—he's got to have someplace to stash all those stuff!) 
My curiosity piqued, I searched for information regarding Spider-Man's pockets and found comic book panels shared on Reddit, where Spider-Man himself mentions the lack of pockets in his suit:

Why does PETER PARKER never add Pockets to his Spider-Man costume?

When you don't have any Pockets in your super suit!!


Of course, in the world of comics, such inconsistencies might simply be attributed to the varying interpretations and artistic liberties taken by different writers and artists.  However, this makes the burger-in-the-pocket scenario all the more intriguing.
Has any Spider-Man media ever explicitly addressed the extent to which Spider-Man can carry items in his pockets? Is there some secret Spider-tech at play here, or are they just mundane pockets?
Understanding the mechanics behind Spider-Man's pocket technology (or lack thereof) could shed light on the practicalities of superhero suit design and the thought processes that go into balancing functionality with aesthetics.

Very well, thank you!

It's Hammer(space)Time!

"this makes the burger-in-the-pocket scenario all the more intriguing" — we didn't think the burger-in-the-pocket scenario could get more intriguing, but we were wrong.

They're "bigger on the inside™".

What has it got in its pocketses, precious? Nasty little hobbits, ummm .. I mean spiders
